# One option to display as dropdown and select in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have an Option named color. it is of type Choose > image. this is assigned to many products with each product containing different option values. is there any way I can create exact copy of this option and display it with different name.

Example: The current option name is Color, I want an exact copy of this option to be named as Second Color. Every product containing Color should have Second color.

And Once I copy and assign this is there any way I can display both these options as dropdown as well?

Thanks

Comment: the answer to your question appears to be: "Yes", since it is a yes or no question.  If you want help with code, please make some attempts, post something you've tried and let us know where it's going wrong.  This is not a place to find people to write code for you, but you will surely find many who would love to help you learn if you show some initiative.

Comment: Well That was kind of like yes/no question. I know how to display one option multiple times or in any option type but the issue i was having was no matter how many copies you have of that option only one type was displayed in cart. Even if I label it as Color 1 and color 2 the last option was displayed in cart.

Comment: As of now i just created another div on product.tpl file and called the options and i also gave a condition if option[name] was color 1 show it as select type and label it as color 2. it is taking values of second color only.

Comment: You don't really need to modify the view.  The correct way to do this would be to simply add a second option to each product.

Comment: Manually adding is impossible. making a second option with exact values can be done but i did not see anywhere in controller file where i can say like if option name is color 1 assign same option values. 

I just found this, can i do something like this <code> if(option['name'] == 'color 1' || option['name'] == 'color 2')</code> Something like this and just say foreach $option[product_option_value] as option_value?

Comment: Why would adding more options be impossible?  Every option for every product has a unique `product option id` so if you want unique instances in the cart you'll have to add them to the product just the same as you added the first one.

Comment: Because there are around 10,000 products. Manually adding them would be real time consuming.

Comment: Well the options need to be added for each product.  You don't necessarily have to add them "manually" but the end result should be the same.  In other words, now's your chance to get creative with MySQL and Php.